# JavaScript Using the DOM And Changing Colors

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Hey guys i have some code here that dynamically changes the background color of the Paragragh HTML elements using Javascript to get at those elements.. My problem in my code is that it shows Yellow stripes opposed to changing the whole paragraph text yellow and not coloring the background of my button.

It's just a learning exercise but, I would like know how to correct this.

Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/VcZdM/

```
  var $ = function (id)
  {
     return document.getElementById(id);
  }
    function processInfo()
  {
   var myPara = $("mypara");
   myPara.style.color = "blue";
   var myParent = myPara.parentNode;


   var TagName = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   for (i=0;i<TagName.length;i++)
   {
   TagName[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   }

   }
   window.onload = function ()
   {
   $("changecolor").onclick = processInfo;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell what you're referring to with the yellow stripes is just because you have multiple paragraphs, if you wanted the whole background to be yellow set it to the div containing those paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you. You were the only person that answered my question. Setting the div did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `window.onload` function, just remove it as you have selected `onLoad` your fiddle, under `framework and extension`. You should select the `no wrap (head) option`

```
$("changecolor").onclick = processInfo;
```

intead of

```
window.onload = function ()
{
  $("changecolor").onclick = processInfo;
}
```

However, in **web page your implementation is correct**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VcZdM/2/)

[**Demo With window.onload**](http://jsfiddle.net/VcZdM/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.
In jsfiddle, you should select the no wrap (head) option.

[***LINK***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014090/why-i-cant-make-a-jsfiddle-of-this-working-code)

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VcZdM/3/) after the changes.

Or just remove `window.onload`